# Is there a way to specify int size in C?

Tags: c, types

I'm trying to check some homework answers about overflow for 2's complement addition, subtraction, etc. and I'm wondering if I can specify the size of a data type. For instance if I want to see what happens when I try to assign -128 or -256 to a 7-bit unsigned int.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint

Comment: I'm a total programming noob, I can set chars to int values and they'll hold? Also unsigned char isn't 7-bit is it?

Comment: `char` has the smallest size available. It is 8 or more bits.

Comment: `unsigned char x = 3;` will indeed work.  C is happy to do so.

Comment: Ok so it's not possible to have a data type that's exactly 7-bit or 9-bit?

Comment: No, unless you count [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field) as distinct types.

Comment: If you want to know how C works, read the standard. C11 draft standard, `6.3 Conversions, 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers, Section 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.`

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Guess I will have to find another way to check my answers.

Comment: @EOF *"if you want to know how C works, read the standard"* The standard is impenetrable for a new programmer, certainly not the place to start when you're trying to wrap your head around the basics of imperative coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On further reading I see you wanted bit sizes that are not normal ones, such as 7 bit and 9 bit etc.
You can achieve this using bitfields

```
struct bits9
{
    int x : 9;
};
```

Now you can use this type `bits9` which has one field in it `x` that is only 9 bits in size.

```
struct bits9    myValue;

myValue.x = 123;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using built in types you have things like:

```
 char      value1;      // 8 bits
 short     value2;      // 16 bits
 long      value3;      // 32 bits
 long long value4;      // 64 bits
```

Note this is the case with Microsoft's compiler on Windows. The C standard does not specify exact widths other than "this one must be at least as big as this other one" etc.
If you only care about a specific platform you can print out the sizes of your types and use those once you have figured them out.

Alternatively you can use `stdint.h` which is in the C99 standard. It has types with the width in the name to make it clear

```
int8_t    value1;    // 8 bits
int16_t   value2;    // 16 bits
int32_t   value3;    // 32 bits
int64_t   value4;    // 64 bits
```

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary sized value, you can use [bitfields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) in structs. For example for a 7-bit value:

```
struct something {
   unsigned char field:7;
   unsigned char padding:1;
};
struct something value;
value.field = -128;
```

Answer (score 0):

The smallest size you have have is char which is an 8 bit integer.  You can have unsigned and signed chars.  Take a look at the stdint.h header.  It defines a int types for you in a platform independent way.  Also there is no such thing as an 7 bit integer.

Comment: `char` is *at least* 8 bits.

Comment: Well 7-bits is a hypothetical size for homework questions I have. It asks to determine if there's overflow when you put certain positive and negative values into 7, 8, and 9-bit processors. I was trying to check my answers with C, but I guess I can't.